# Calendar / Timeline Control for Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm searching for a day / timeline control for android. Something similar to the following:

[image: Day View in iOS]

Could someone please point me in the right direction?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically made some changes to the following code sample and got it working:

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

The [Google IO conference application](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) has a similar UI . Check that.

Comment: Many thanks for the response, but how exactly will looking at this app guide me in the right direction? I know what I want to accomplish, just not really sure how to do it?

Comment: Its not the exactly but it similar view like timeline.